# Tidying messy data - collecting all observations from a particular statistical unit to one row

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

I have quite a large dataset in R where all observations from all time-points are assigned as variables (columns). The problem is that for one particular statistical unit there is also one row assigned to each time-point so the data frame looks following:

```
Unit   TIME    VAR1-time1  VAR2-time1 VAR3-time1 VAR1-time2 VAR2-time2 VAR3-time2 VAR1-time3 VAR2-time3 VAR3-time3     
 1     time1      2.0         Stuff      4.0         NA         NA       NA         NA          NA           NA
 1     time2       NA          NA         NA         4.0       Stuff     2.0        NA          NA           NA
 1     time3       NA          NA         NA         NA         NA       NA         2.0        Stuff         4.0
 2     time1      2.0         Stuff      4.0         NA         NA       NA         NA          NA           NA
 2     time2       NA          NA         NA         4.0       Stuff     2.0        NA          NA           NA
 2     time3       NA          NA         NA         NA         NA       NA         2.0        Stuff         4.0
 3     time1      2.0         Stuff      4.0         NA         NA       NA         NA          NA           NA
 3     time2       NA          NA         NA         4.0       Stuff     2.0        NA          NA           NA
 3     time3       NA          NA         NA         NA         NA       NA         2.0        Stuff         4.0
```

Data in the rows are stored in correct columns but TIME variable in this case is useless since variables (columns) themselves already contain the information about the timepoint. 
I would like to get rid of multiple rows for each time point and have all the data from one particular unit on one row.

Is there a convinient way to tidy up this kind of data? Maybe with dplyr or tidyR-package? The data frame has thousands of different variables (columns) with hundreds of different timepoints (rows) for each statistical unit.

```
df %>% 
group_by(Unit) %>%
summarise_all(mean,na.rm=T)
```

Seems to do it quite well, still having problems with different types of variables, using mean-function does not play well with variables that are not numeric or logical. The original data frame has many different types of variables, such as: numeric, logical, calendar dates and times, character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the excellent `pivot_longer` from `tidyr` for this:

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("VAR"),
               names_to = c(".value", "time"),  # creates column "time" and a column for every "VAR"
               names_pattern = "(VAR.*)-time(.*)",  # extracts relevant parts from column names
               values_drop_na = TRUE) # remove NAs
```

Note that the `TIME` column can be dropped because this information is extracted from the column names and stored in the `time` column.

Result:

```
   Unit TIME  time   VAR1 VAR2   VAR3
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
1     1 time1 1         2 Stuff     4
2     1 time2 2         4 Stuff     2
3     1 time3 3         2 Stuff     4
4     2 time1 1         2 Stuff     4
5     2 time2 2         4 Stuff     2
6     2 time3 3         2 Stuff     4
7     3 time1 1         2 Stuff     4
8     3 time2 2         4 Stuff     2
9     3 time3 3         2 Stuff     4
```